# <div> with contentEditable doesn't change immidiately, only the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, innerhtml

I've got 2 `<div>`'s, both contentEditable with values from a database.
It works displaying them and changing them **BUT** only the second time.
e.g. :

- Clicking on the #stuff div
- alerts me the value from the DB ( something like "Weather's ok" )
- I change it to "New Value"
- Clicking outside the div
- Function alerting me the value from #stuff div ( **still** "Weather's okay" )
- Clicking again inside the div and it **now** alerts me "New Value"

This leads to having to go into the div twice for it to accept the changes..
I tried it manualy to open save.php with the parameters and it saved directly!
I'm pretty sure this is something basic what I'm missing but I cant figure it out yet..

HTML :

```
<div id="test-container" style="border: 1px solid green;">
    <div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
        <?php echo $rst["content"]; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="stuff" contentEditable="true">
        <?php echo $rst["stuff"]; ?>
    </div>

    <button id="save">Save Changes</button>
</div>
```

JS Function(s) :

```
var content = "";
var from = "";

/*
The code below shows the save button if anywhere in the editable div is clicked, 
and hide the button if anywhere outside the div is clicked.
*/

$("#editable, #stuff").click(function (e) {
    content = $(this).html();
    from = (this.id);

    alert(content);
    $("#save").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    alert(content);
    $("#save").hide();

});

/*
The code below gets the data from the content variable and posts to the send.php file.
If the data is posted successfuly, the PHP file recieves the data and inserts to database, where the field is based on the form variable. 
*/

$("#save").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        data: {
        content: content,
        from : from
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: TIP: You don't need that `if ... else` inside your `click` event handler.

Comment: `content = $('#editable').html()` = `content = $(this).html()`. The same applies to `#stuff`.

Comment: Also, are you wrapping your event handlers with `document ready`?

Comment: I wasn't sure how else he could detect which of those selectors fired.. or does JS do this automatically?
EDIT : No, not wrapping them

Comment: You attached an event handler (`click`) to a selector. This selector will return to you which one received the event, if it could be many (in your scenario, it could be 2 elements).

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve (press F12 in your browser so you can see the console to monitor the results)? http://jsfiddle.net/6Y9gd/

Comment: Actually, this one is better: http://jsfiddle.net/6Y9gd/1/

Comment: Yes! That was my thought. I've took your first fiddle and changed from console.log to alert(just to see aswell) and it worked. But when I added the ajax call in the 2nd function I get a double "Uncaught TypeError : Illegal invocation"

Comment: I'm not sure you can work out the ajax call within jsFiddle.

Comment: But basically, I think you should drop the idea of monitoring the `document` `click` event and go through another route. Check out my second jsFiddle I've posted as a second comment.

Comment: I see! I've found out that it's the from he dies at. `content` works like a charm, howether `from` is alerted as a [object Object]  
**EDIT : ** I've changed the `var from` to `var fromID` and added `fromID = (this.id);` in the focus function - Seems to be working now!

Comment: Yes, it's actually an object in the example I've posted. You can retrieve its `id` or other properties by `dot notation` in Vanilla Javascript (`object.id`) or using `.attr()` if you're using jQuery (`$(selector).attr("id")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I found in your code is:

> after the keyboard input DOM is updated not variable.

Try this:-

```
var content = "";
var from = "";

$("#editable, #stuff").click(function (e) {
    content = $(this).html();
    from = $(this.id);    
    console.log(content);
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    console.log(content);
});
$("#editable, #stuff").keyup(function(){
  content = $(this).html();
  from = $(this.id);
});
```

[click here for the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xK0nB1n/gu5LE/)